# Login with google is temporarily disabled for this app

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-signin

Our application has over the last 3 years been using Google login in order to create Google Docs, Sheets and Slides from inside our application - as well as displaying the user's Google Calendar from inside our application.

We're now suddenly experiencing that when we e.g. try to create a new Google Doc and try to login, then we get "**login with google is temporarily disabled for this app**".

We've been checking the OAuth Consent Screen, where the app is in "**Being verified**" status. The information says that the review process could take up to 4-6 weeks. However, the app has been in this state for several months (if not more than 1 year).

Every now and then we get an email from Google asking us to provide information for the verification process. It's always the same information that we're asked to provide - and we've done so. But the app has not changed to a **Verified** state. So the process seems to be looping around in circles.

Anyone who can help - and know how to sort this out?

Since we're on the bronze support package, we're not eligible for any calls/chat with the technical support team.

We've been trying to follow the process as described by Google - as well as following advice and suggestions on Stackoverflow for this issue, which seems to be affecting other applications as well. So far, without luck unfortunately.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming, as well as: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions)

Comment: Also see [Better protection against Man in the Middle phishing attacks](https://security.googleblog.com/2019/04/better-protection-against-man-in-middle.html).

Comment: Hi Martin, I do understand your comment about this based on the input above. 
However, the issue seems to be quite uncommon. And since following every steps outlined by Google, and things seems to be looping around, we are really curious to understand if/and how others who have experience the same pattern have been able to sort this out.

Comment: In case this is some kind of hybrid app, on Android this counts as CEF... and the URL might not be visible. Likely quite a few people experienced this and are doomed to either migrate to Android SDK or forget about their app. Mozilla also purged lots of Firefox extensions two weeks ago.

Comment: I mean, from a security perspective... I can show you the official oAuth2 consent screen and then perhaps let you post your credentials to my web-server and then have access to your Google account, at least for a limited amount of time. That's exactly how MITM attacks in a `WebView` do work. And they don't differ in between "good" and "bad" guys, but have eliminated this possibility altogether.

Comment: Input to users with the same issue: we managed to get some progress on this by contacting the Billing team (which is not completely obvious). They raised a ticket with the Trust and Safety team who you can't really get in touch with through other channels. 

I'll update this question as soon as I have more information on how (we hopefully) managed to solved this issue.

FYI: Apparently, the issue is not to be handled by the Technical Support Team, as it's only handled by the Trust and Safety team. Hope that's valuable information for others in the same situation.

Comment: The question does not even tell which kind of application it is - for regular hosted web-applications this should be no problem at all, but for web-applications running in a `WebView`, it is quite likely a problem - and the blog posts explains which applications are affected and why. Unless the URL is clearly visible, this can potentially be used for phishing account credentials. Based on your response, I'd say: the hope dies last.